# url loosing extentions on redirection .net

Tags: url-rewriting

net site on a shared hosted server with plesk as admin panel. And I want my 404 redirected to default page to handle extentionless urls

I have in the plesk panel pointed with url the following.
Error  description     type      location
404     Not found      Url      http://iservice.iwebdesigner.org
however when I use the url like this http://iservice.iwebdesigner.org/user
it redirects to the default page but looses the /user. I believe the type which is not available on plesk needs to be set to execute url for iis. Is there a way of changing that in plesk? or what else can I do. I am not sure is web config settings can help as iis will have already redirected the page and the extension gone before web config settings can run.

The hosting people say the cant make any changes what so ever to iis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured it out. For those of you trying to use the urlrewriter module
in your shared hosted server. This rule below handles non existent extentionless
url and redirects to default.aspx for processing. e.g www.mysite/user. Once you
have set the 404 error page to point to the default.aspx as above in plesk(Type
must be url and the path set to default.aspx), upload the UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll
to your bin folder. in web config

```
<configsections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet"`enter code here`
             requirePermission ="false"
             type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"  />
  </configsections>
<urlrewritingnet rewriteonlyvirtualurls="true" contextitemsprefix="QueryString" defaultpage="default.aspx"
    defaultprovider="RegEx" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>
      <add name="ExtensionlessRewrite" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="/default.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
   </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
<system.webserver>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </modules>
  </system.webserver>
```

That worked for me echo